# Why is the print command after time.sleep not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I know there are many other ways to solve a problem like this but i would love to know why this code isn't working..

```
import shutil
import os  # Access to some functions of the operating system
import time

def auto_backup():
    source_dir = r'C:\Users\Derma\OneDrive\Desktop\back'
    target_dir = r'C:\Users\Derma\OneDrive\Desktop\test'

    file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)
    while True:
        for file_name in file_names:
            shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), target_dir)
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Executed")

auto_backup()
```

The problem is: The program does the `shutil` command but doesn't execute the `print` function call. Why?

Comment: You need to flush the output buffer if you want to see print results immediately - [How can I flush the output of the print function (unbuffer python output)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-can-i-flush-the-output-of-the-print-function-unbuffer-python-output)

Comment: Assuming `file_names` isn't empty, the print _must_ be happening.  How are you running this code?  Are you running it with `python myscript.py` on the command line, or are you using an IDE, or something else?

Comment: Right -- if you are using an IDE or redirecting the output using `>`, then buffering is definitely the problem.  The output is being produced, but not being shown.

Comment: @shriakhilc stdout is line-buffered by default, so I'm not sure flushing will help.

Comment: Thanks for both answers, i think it was a mix of both..

Comment: Either post the solution as an answer below or delete the question. Don't replace the question text with "solved", that's useless.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Comment: No one has mentioned that fact that the `auto_backup()` function in your question contains an infinite loop and will never return…

Comment: @martineau nor the fact that `shutil.move` is a bad way to do a backup.

Comment: @MarkRansom which way would you recommend?
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Well `move` will generally delete the original when it's done, which is why I called it a bad choice.  `copy` would almost certainly be better.